# how to send message from rabbitMQ to iot hub device?

Tags: php, azure, rabbitmq, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send message from rabbitMQ to IoT hub device named as `dvc-test` with php, i referred official [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) and tried the `send.php` code like below:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$host = '[MYHUBNAME].azure-devices.net';
$userName = 'XXXXXXXX'; //confused which iot hub crediential should comes device or iothub
$password = 'XXXXXXXX'; //confused which iot hub crediential should comes device or iothub
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($host, 5672, $userName, $password);
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
$json = '{"id":1, "value":"test"}';
$msg = new AMQPMessage($json);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

echo " [x] Sent ";

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

It worked for localhost with default given parameteres given in documentation, But if i tried with iot hub credientials it does not work for me.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Please check rabbitmq logs if you see any connections from your ip.
If there is nothing in log, then maybe some firewall is blocking amqp connection.

BTW, I assume that you are sending messages TO rabbimq, not from.

Comment: No i want to send only message to IoT hub device by ampq protocol for this i am using rabitmq

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example [here](https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/connecting-to-the-azure-iot-hub-using-an-the-amqp-stack/) how to send messages with low level AMQP. For the authentication you need to generate a SAS token based on your device key.

Comment: I have seen this article but it is based on `AMQP .Net Lite` which works for the .Net technologies but in my case i am using php, How can i do it with php?